# Toolbar interfering with Filter a RecyclerView with SearchView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

i'm new to Android studio and I am having trouble implementing a Filter a RecyclerView with SearchView successfully. The searching feature seems to working fine but it seem to be interfering with my toolbar/title. If i'm missing not showing any code let me know. Thank you.

[Image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIsIC.png)

**home_menu.xml**

```
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

**activity_home.xml**

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeActivity"
android:id="@+id/home_rel"
>

<include layout="@layout/desc_toolbar" android:id="@+id/desc_toolbar"/>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/home_RV"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/desc_toolbar"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    />
```

**desc_toolbar.xml**

```
androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/desc_toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the height of RelativeLayout in desc_toolbar.xml to `wrap_content`?

Comment: Yea, I tried changing layout_height to wrap_content and no difference.